# python pyodbc - connecting to sql server 2008 on windows/python2.7 but not on centOS6.32/python2.6.6

Tags: python, linux, pyodbc

I have the following code:

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};"
                      +"SERVER=something.example.com;"
                      +"DATABASE=something;")

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

name=('Smith, Joe', )

cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM Users WHERE displayname=?', name)
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
        print row
```

The code executes as desired on windows/python2.7. However, when I try to run it on linux, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/something/script.py", line 125, in <module>
    main()
  File "/something/script.py", line 77, in main
    +"DATABASE=something;")
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

The traceback seems to indicate that the `DRIVER` entry is missing, which isn't the case. Is this a version difference? What is the issue with pyodbc?

EDIT: contents of /etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
# Example driver definitions

# Driver from the postgresql-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[PostgreSQL]
Description     = ODBC for PostgreSQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/psqlodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so
FileUsage       = 1


# Driver from the mysql-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[MySQL]
Description     = ODBC for MySQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage       = 1
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your `odbcinst.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an odbc driver for sql server configured - you need to install and configure one. The drivers section on [unixodbc](http://www.unixodbc.org/drivers.html)'s webpage suggests [freetds](http://www.freetds.org/), alternatively you could also try microsoft's own [implementation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451.aspx).

freedts should be installable using `yum`.

The basic configuration then should look something like this:

`/etc/odbcinst.ini`:

```
[SQL Server]
Description = FreeTDS driver for SQL Server
Driver = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Driver64 = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so
```

Now you should already be able to connect. For more detailled information on configuration, look [here](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/).

edit:

alternatively there are also other ways to connect to an sql server from python, like [python-tds](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-tds), [pymssql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymssql) and [more...](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SQL%20Server)